# Methods for enabling/disabling passcode lock based on device connection in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I tried searching around, but couldn't come up with much on the topic of this.

Is there an API or code within various Security API's that would allow some sort of passcode locking mechanism to enable whenever a device is connected (by Bluetooth, etc) and disable whenever said device is paired with the phone?  An interesting concept I had thought up earlier today but can't seem to determine a method available for this.

The concept is pretty much this: if the phone is close enough to be connected over Bluetooth to the device (would be something like a smartwatch or other wearable computing) then the phone is on you and passcode entry can be disabled.  However, when the device is not found by the iPhone, there is a physical distance between the two devices and the phone should lock up and not allow entry.  This could even be some form of superficial lock mechanism on some apps (which exists already) that could activate based on this proximity awareness.  This method is meant to failsafe by being a "lock first, then check" mentality that is paired to a specific address of the wearable computing.  This could, in theory, be hacked, yes, but for general usage allows a user to have a no-maintenance method that can save some passcode entries from time to time should one find it annoying, but still want it's security potential.

Again, this idea is based on the assumption that said device connecting to your iPhone that the phone itself is searching for is physically latched to you somehow.

Thanks and I appreciate any sort of input or direction.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?